# Why is $\exp(z^{-1})$ an essential singularity?

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm reading [Conway's complex analysis book](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=9LtfZr1snG0C&printsec=frontcover&hl=pt-BR&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false) and on page 105 he defines a pole as:

> **Definition:** If $z=a$ is an isolated singularity of $f$, then $a$ is a pole of $f$ if $\lim_{z\to a}|f(z)|=\infty$.

There is also a characterization theorem on page 103:

> **Theorem:** If $f$ has an isolated singularity at $a$ then the point $z=a$ is a removable singularity iff $$\lim_{z\to a}(z-a)f(z)=0$$

I'm trying to use these facts to prove the assertion he made on page 105:

[image]

Knowing that an essential singularity is neither a pole nor a removable singularity, how can I prove $\exp(z^{-1})$ has an essential singularity at $z=0$?

Comment: I start with essential singularity = isolated singularity which is not dominated by any power of $(z-a)$, i.e. there is a path to $a$ where $|f(z)|$ grows much faster than $(z-a)^k$ for any $k$. Then, I prove that every isolated singularity is a pole or an essential singularity (a removable singularity being some sort of pole of order $0$). All this reduce to proving the [Riemann theorem on removable singularities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity#Riemann.27s_theorem) , the Laurent series theorems, and the Liouville theorem.

Comment: Use its Laurent expansion.

Comment: $z=0$ is not a pole, since the limit from the left is $0$ and not $\infty$.  It is not a removable singularity since the limit from the right of $zf(z)$ is not $0$.

Comment: @Starfall : If you already proved everything, it is obvious that it is an essential singularity. But what do you prove before saying "use its Laurent expansion" ?

Comment: The definition of $ \exp $ is usually gvien by the Taylor series, so it should be trivial to note that the Laurent expansion has a singularity at $ z = 0 $ which is not of finite order.

Comment: @GEdgar For me $\lim_{z\to 0} |e^{1/z}|=\infty$, since $1/z$ goes to infinity, when the limit is from the right.

Comment: When $z \to 0^-$, we have $1/z \to -\infty$ and $e^{1/z} \to 0$ so of course $|e^{1/z}| \to 0$.  So the limit is not $\infty$.

Comment: @GEdgar It's true, thanks! Regarding your second assertion how do you get $\lim_{z\to 0^+} ze^{1/z}\neq 0$?

Comment: that's part of Riemann's theorem on removable singularities that if $|f(z)|$ grows faster that $|z-a|^{-k}$  for every $k$, then $|f(z)|$ doesn't have a limit when $z \to a$ (i.e. $\lim_{z \to a} |f(z)|$ depends on which path $z \to a$), the theorem then proves that if $a$ is an isolated singularity and if $\lim_{z \to a} |f(z)| = \infty$ (for every path $z \to a$ !!) then $z=a$ is a pole (of finite order !!) and $f(z) (z-a)^k$ is holomorphic for some $k$

Comment: $\implies$ there are many things to prove from the simple definitions pole/essential singularity

Comment: In fact $ze^{1/z} \to +\infty$ as $z \to 0^+$.  If you don't know how to prove that, perhaps you should review elementary calculus.